# Re-expressing exterior derivative acting on interior product

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

In (5+1) spacetime dimensions suppose we have a scalar field $a$ and a $3$-form field $$A=\frac{1}{3!}A_{[\mu_1\mu_2\mu_3]}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge dx^{\mu_2}\wedge dx^{\mu_3}.$$ $da$ is the exterior derivative of $a$. We denote the [interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) of $da$ with $A$ by $\iota_{da}A$. Is it possible to write $d(\iota_{da}A)$ in terms of $\iota_{da}dA$? Is it possible to express $d(\iota_{da}A)$ in any other way by using some exterior algebra identities?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formula

Comment: Is there a metric to turn the 1-form $\mathrm{d}a$ into a vector field?

Comment: The metric is (1+5) dimensional Minkowski metric.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly comprehensive list of useful identities for operations on $p$-forms:
\begin{align}
&i_Xi_Y+i_Yi_X=0,\tag{1}\\
&{\mathcal L}_X i_Y-i_Y {\mathcal L}_X=i_{[X,Y]},\tag{2}\\
&{\mathcal L}_X{\mathcal L}_Y-{\mathcal L}_Y{\mathcal L}_X ={\mathcal L}_{[X,Y]},\tag{3}\\
&di_X+i_Xd={\mathcal L}_X,\tag{4}\\
&d{\mathcal L}_X-{\mathcal L}_Xd=0,\tag{5}\\
&d^2=0.\tag{6}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Is $i_{[X,Y]}=i_Xi_Y-i_Yi_X$ or something else?

Comment: @vyali  I don't think that there can be any connection between $i_{X,Y}$ and $i_X i_Y-i_Yi_X$ as the former needs information about derivatives and the latter does not.

Comment: What is $i_{[X,Y]}$?

Comment: Sorry I meant $i_{[X,Y]}$ not $i_{X,Y}$ (too late to edit now!).  I.e interior multiplication by the Lie bracket of the $X$, $Y$ fields.